# React: Method to create inputs from template tags in a string of html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, loops, state

Phew okay here we go...

I have a string of HTML that comes from an API response.  It's HTML that builds an email template.  Within that HTML that's returned there are multiple instances of template tags defined by double curly brackets {{ }}.

**Part 1**

What I would like to achieve is creating a function that finds all instances of a template tag, **{{ tag }}**.  Once found I would like to create an object with all the key's being those tags, stripped of the brackets, that could be saved to the state.

So let's say the html contains these tags

- {{ title }}
- {{ sub_title }}
- {{ caption }}
- {{ body_text }}

We would create an object looking like

```
{
    "title": " ",
    "sub_title" ; " ",
    "caption": " ",
    "body_text": " "
}
```

and save it to the state.  this.state.inputs for example

**Part 2**

With this object in the state, we can create a number of inputs with the name attribute set to the object key.

```
<input name="title" />
<input name="sub_title" />
<input name="caption" />
<input name="body" />
```

**Part 3**

This I know how to approach, it would be updating state with the value of those inputs.  Not a problem.

What do you think the best method to approach this problem would be?  Discussion is always welcome.  I would like to learn how to approach these types of problems.

Answer (score 0):

How about making a function and running the for statement as shown below?
Below is an idea, not an exact action code.

```js
let object1 = {
    "title": " ",
    "sub_title" ; " ",
    "caption": " ",
    "body_text": " "
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  <input className={key} props={value}/>
}
```

Comment: Tags are unknown, so they must be dynamic.  I was able to complete the first, part.  working through the rest now.  Will post answer if I get it.

Comment: It doesn't matter if object1 is dynamic. Whether stored in useState, it can be dynamically created with for or map. I look forward to your own solution.